# using another database name with dotnetnuke

Tags: dotnetnuke

i've a simple question.

Is it possible to use another database name as the readme says it have to be called "DotNetNuke" ?

> - manually create SQL Server database named "DotNetNuke" ( using Enterprise Manager or your tool of choice )

i've a webhost which have different database names.

thanks

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use any database name that you would like.  During the installation process, you provide your database name.

Comment: ok thanks.. i was just confused because it told me i have to create a database named "DotNetNuke" =)

Answer (score 0):

You can also manually edit the connection string in the web.config file.  By doing this the Auto install option will still be available.